# Merging dataframes of different length

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two data frames which look like this,

df1:

```
SP1          Count1
ANDGER        2
CARCRA        4
CAR           3
PANVIR        1
```

and df2:

```
SP2          Count2
CARCRA        7
CAR           6
PANVIR        4
```

I want to merge them together based on matching id's in the first column (SP1 in df1 and SP2 in df2) but I want to retain the id's that are only in one of the dataframes still.

My desired output is:

```
Species     Count1  Count2
ANDGER        2       NaN
CARCRA        4        7
CAR           3        6
PANVIR        1        4
```

I have tried:

```
df1.set_index('SP1')
df2.set_index('SP2')
pd.merge(df1, df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but it doesn't retain items that don't match.

Edit:

For what its worth the code that worked for me is:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat()`.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ===========================
df1

      SP1  Count1
0  ANDGER       2
1  CARCRA       4
2     CAR       3
3  PANVIR       1

df2

      SP2  Count2
0  CARCRA       7
1     CAR       6
2  PANVIR       4

# processing
# ==========================
pd.concat([df1.set_index('SP1'), df2.set_index('SP2')], axis=1, join='outer')

        Count1  Count2
ANDGER       2     NaN
CAR          3       6
CARCRA       4       7
PANVIR       1       4
```

Comment: hmmm, its throwing the error `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: @StefanoPotter Can you upload your real data file pls? The code works perfectly for the sample data you gave.

Comment: Its a pretty big file, and I'm not sure how to upload to stackexchange, but you are correct your code works.  I will try to work out what is throwing it for a loop

Comment: @StefanoPotter Better groupby if you have duplicate entries in the columns using which you are merging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` as follows

```
print pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='SP1', right_on='SP2', how='outer')
      SP1  Count1     SP2  Count2
0  ANDGER       2     NaN     NaN
1  CARCRA       4  CARCRA       7
2     CAR       3     CAR       6
3  PANVIR       1  PANVIR       4
```

Better groupby if you have duplicate entries in the columns using which you are merging.

Comment: I have used groupby before, but I am not sure how to in this instance